# Applying CSS animation to text - how to do it properly?

Tags: css, css-animations, blur

How to properly apply animation to **Text A** and **Text B** so that they gradually turn from being [blurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0xS9.jpg) to non-blurred?

The animation itself is simple and ready:

```
@keyframes unblur {
from { filter: blur(6px); }
to { filter: blur(0); }
}
```

The question is **where** to place the following code to, so that animation is applied to both - Text A and Text B:

```
animation-name: unblur;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-duration: 1.2s;
```

The [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwL5gatj/) (text is blurred, but the unblur-code quoted above is not in the fiddle yet).

**UPDATE: SOLVED. Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already applied the `blur_filter` class to both `TEXT A` and `TEXT B` elements, you can simply write those animation properties inside the class.

Try This:

```css
.blur_filter {
 animation-name: unblur;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 animation-duration: 1.2s;
}
@keyframes unblur {
 from { filter: blur(6px); }
 to { filter: blur(0); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in your css and remove the filter: blur(6px); from .blur_filter class

```
.blur_filter {
 animation: unblur 3s;
}
```

Here is the Example [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/4wvuejar/)